# Re-center a label with each even in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, label, center

I'm building a simple WFA with a label that changes and gives instructions to the user as they work their way through the program.

Is there a way to programmatically re-center the label horizontally after each text change so that the label is always centered in the form regardless of what text is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. After you change the text (assuming here your Label is called Label1):

```
Me.Label1.Left = Me.ClientSize.Width \ 2 - Me.Label1.Width \ 2
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! Thank you kindly.